# MySQL group by null and not null values

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a table like this:

```sql
id | cluster_id | user_id | name      | ...
1  | 1          | 1       | test name
2  | 1          | 3       | other
3  | null       | 1       | one more
4  | 2          | 1       | foo
5  | null       | 1       | bar
6  | 1          | 1       | baz
```

I'd like to create a query that groups by the `cluster_id` column but only group by the columns that have a not null value so that I get something like this:

```sql
id | cluster_id | user_id | ...
1  | 1          | 1       | test name
3  | null       | 1       | one more
4  | 2          | 1       | foo
5  | null       | 1       | bar
```

I'd like to a list with distinct cluster_ids, but only where the cluster_id is not null. Also I'd like to filter on arbitrary columns like `user_id`.

In the above result I also query on the `user_id`, where the `user_id` is 1.

How do I create such a query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this looks the same , can you create a [mre] so that we can understand what you try to achive

Comment: @nbk I’ve updated the question. It should be more clear now I hope:)

Comment: Hmm, `the columns that have a not null value` and your example goal table has a null in it - not too sure what you're trying to achieve there.

Comment: @LukeBriggs fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is simple.

The GROUP BY also works with NULL Values

I made two queries, the first includes the user_id the last not

You must test this with id as primary key, and see if excluding the NULL brings some performance

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `cluster_id` int,
>   `user_id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(20)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   (`id`, `cluster_id`, `user_id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '1', 'test name'),
>   ('2', '1', '3', 'other'),
>   ('3', null, '1', 'one more'),
>   ('4', '2', '1', 'foo'),
>   ('5', null, '1', 'bar'),
>   ('6', '1', '1', 'baz');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM  tab1 WHERE `id` IN (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM tab1 GROUP BY `cluster_id`,`user_id`)
> UNION 
> SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE `cluster_id` IS NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> id | cluster_id | user_id | name     
> -: | ---------: | ------: | :--------
>  1 |          1 |       1 | test name
>  2 |          1 |       3 | other    
>  3 |       null |       1 | one more 
>  4 |          2 |       1 | foo      
>  5 |       null |       1 | bar
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM  tab1 WHERE `id` IN (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM tab1 WHERE `cluster_id` IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `cluster_id`,`user_id`)
> UNION 
> SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE `cluster_id` IS NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> id | cluster_id | user_id | name     
> -: | ---------: | ------: | :--------
>  1 |          1 |       1 | test name
>  2 |          1 |       3 | other    
>  4 |          2 |       1 | foo      
>  3 |       null |       1 | one more 
>  5 |       null |       1 | bar
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM  tab1 WHERE `id` IN (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM tab1 GROUP BY `cluster_id`)
> UNION 
> SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE `cluster_id` IS NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> id | cluster_id | user_id | name     
> -: | ---------: | ------: | :--------
>  1 |          1 |       1 | test name
>  3 |       null |       1 | one more 
>  4 |          2 |       1 | foo      
>  5 |       null |       1 | bar
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM  tab1 WHERE `id` IN (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM tab1 WHERE `cluster_id` IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `cluster_id`)
> UNION 
> SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE `cluster_id` IS NULL
> ```
>
> ```
> id | cluster_id | user_id | name     
> -: | ---------: | ------: | :--------
>  1 |          1 |       1 | test name
>  4 |          2 |       1 | foo      
>  3 |       null |       1 | one more 
>  5 |       null |       1 | bar
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ae7ea64b403e362eec83cfa325f039c)*

Comment: When the `cluster_id` is `null` it should not be grouped, only group records with a not null value. This will result in 2 null records in this case.

Comment: i missed that part. mi changed my answer, you must test which is faster

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem I have is that whenever I want to filter out results for a specific user the query will always return results of records with a cluster_id. If I query on `user_id=3` the query always returns records, even when no records with that Id exist.

Comment: that is basic sql add `AND user_id = 3`  after `cluster_id IS NULL`ANd `cluster_id IS NOT NULL` you must understand that union combines two independent queries that have the same structure, so you filter the before UNION or after